# Calculating distances between two tables full of GEOGRAPHY points

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlgeography

I'm using SQL Server.

I have two tables like this:

**Table1**:

```
Column1, Column2, Column3, GeoLoc
-----------------------------------
a        b        c        0xE61...
```

**Table2**:

```
Column1, Column2, Column3, GeoLoc 
-----------------------------------
a        b        c        0xE62...
```

I am looking to get an output table which will compare all of the points in both tables, and show me where `table1` has a `GeoLoc` which is within X distance of `GeoLoc` in `table2`.

Does anyone know how to go about this? One table has around 800 rows, and the other has about 300,000 rows. I'm stumped as to even where to start...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your GeoLoc column is of the 'Geography' data type in SQL server, you should be able to use something like this:

```
select
  t1.*,
  t2.*,
  t1.GeoLoc.STDistance(t2.GeoLoc) as DistanceApart
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on (t1.GeoLoc.STDistance(t2.GeoLoc) <= @distanceX)
```

with the 'DistanceApart' and 'distanceX' values being in meters

Comment: Was just about to suggest the same.  +1

Comment: This is more or less the way I was doing it. I've got the code running now, but obviously this gonna take hell of a while to execute. Will update the question once I know what happens.

Comment: This could be in result of huge resulting data. Suppose you specified such a distance that all locations appeared to locate within it. In such case you will receive output table containing 800 x 300,000 records. Maybe it will be enough for your application business logic to use TOP clause or narrow your query with another condition, say '... and t2.Column1 = t1.Column1'?

Comment: The time taken/resulting data set concerns are all true, but unless you can apply additional filter criteria, it's going to end up being some variant of this - perhaps with a little juggling a more optimised query plan for it, but still largely this kind of thing.

Comment: Sorry, yes result is in meters - I did mean to mention that originally (updated now with an edit)

Comment: Late to the game here but you could try joining on latitude and longitude also. It's not perfect but you could add t2.Latitude < t1.latitude + 0.1 or t2.latitude > t1.latitude - 0.1.