# Given longitude and latitude of two areas, how to find the distance between them in meters. How to query in SQL..?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, google-maps

I basically have two table with ID, Area.Longitude and latitude column.  I need to find the difference in distances that are more than 20 meters apart for each area.

### Table 1

```
##[ID]  [Area]  [Latitude]  [Longitude]##

ID1 Area1   51.51141557 -0.138341652

ID2 Area2   51.50950278 -0.156438192

ID3 Area3   51.5071583  -0.153418937
```

### Table 2

```
##[ID]  [Area]  [Latitude]  [Longitude]##
ID1 Area1    51.50819747    -0.141020749

ID2 Area2    51.50781548    -0.14294574

ID3 Area3    51.51286329    -0.14765827
```

I want to compare table 1( Area 1) and Table 2 ( Area 2) find the difference between them (given in longitude and latitude) and display the results in meters (their distance between them)

### Result##

```
##[ID]  [Area]  [Distance apart in Meter]##

ID1 Area1   5 meter

ID2 Area2   10 meter

ID3 Area3   20 meter
```

How do I write an sql query for to achieve this.  Please [help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4y5x.png)

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747500/calculating-distances-between-two-tables-full-of-geography-points

Comment: Which is it: mysql or sql server? The quality of the answers you're going to get is highly dependent on accurate tagging of the technology you're using.

Answer (score 1):

This is the oracle function We use in our projects to calculate distance. You please modify syntax accordingly to suit mysql / sql-server

```
create or replace
FUNCTION CALC_DISTANCE (Lat1 IN NUMBER,
                                     Lon1 IN NUMBER,
                                     Lat2 IN NUMBER,
                                     Lon2 IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
 -- Convert degrees to radians
 DEGTORAD NUMBER := 57.29577951;
 --Radius NUMBER := 6387.7;  -- For km
   Radius NUMBER := 6387700  -- For metres

BEGIN
  RETURN(NVL(Radius,0) * ACOS((sin(NVL(Lat1,0) / DegToRad) * SIN(NVL(Lat2,0) / DegToRad)) +
        (COS(NVL(Lat1,0) / DegToRad) * COS(NVL(Lat2,0) / DegToRad) *
         Cos(Nvl(Lon2,0) / Degtorad - Nvl(Lon1,0)/ Degtorad))));
END;
```

---

To use this function to get in meters, you can probably use,

```
SELECT
CALC_DISTANCE ('51.51141557' ,'-0.138341652',
              '51.50819747', '-0.141020749') AS DISTANCE
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: "To use this function to get in meters..." Or just use metres for the radius of the Earth instead of kilometres: `Radius NUMBER := 6387700`... (Though that number seems just a touch on the high side, I'd say. The average is 6371km.) Bear in mind that many databases have dedicated support for much faster calculations like this these days using geo extensions of some kind. The best answer depends very much on the RDBMS you're using.

Comment: @MattGibson: Answer edited appropriately. Thank you for your input.